Saving plots in multiple columns using ggsave() cuts 2/3 of output
I created 200 * 3 plots (3 rows, 200 columns). I need to save them all in one pdf file on a single page. The code itself does not trigger any errors or warnings but the upper two graphs are being cut and are not visible in the pdf. Changing the width and height did not solve the problem. It also occurs when plotting 50 columns per page.
I used the follwing code to save the data:
ggsave("allplots.pdf", arrangeGrob(grobs = List_allplots, ncol=200), device = "pdf",
        width = 2000, height = 20,
        units = c("cm"), dpi = 1000, limitsize = FALSE)

Adding nrow = 1 or nrow = 3 does not fix the issue.
List_allplots consists of a patchwork with 200 items (3 patch areas, 1 col, 3 rows each). Plot margins are set to 0.
I tried to save one list item per page, which worked (no cuts). I found that ggsave sometimes outputs cut pdfs, unfortunately none of the provided solutions worked for me.
I reproduced the error with the following code using iris (only Plot3 are visible in the 1-page pdf):
example1 <- function(x)
{
Plot1 <- ggplot(iris[x,], aes(x= Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point()

Plot2 <- ggplot(iris[x,], aes(x= Species, y=Sepal.Width))+
  geom_point()

Plot3 <- ggplot(iris[x,], aes(x= Species, y=Petal.Length))+
  geom_point()

Plot1 / Plot2 / Plot3
}

vec <- c(1:150)

ListP <- lapply(vec, example1)

ggsave("test.pdf", arrangeGrob(grobs = ListP, ncol=150), device = "pdf",
       width = 1500, height = 20,
       units = c("cm"), dpi = 300, limitsize = FALSE)

edit: The number of columns does not trigger the issue with cut plots.

600 figures on a single page?

Yes, I know... I was asked to do it that way by my boss.

On an A4 page, with three columns of graphs, the height of each graph will be around 1mm.  My eyesight isn't that good.  My printer's resolution isn't that good...

It's not supposed to be a A4 png thingy but a pdf vector graphic.  One can actually zoom in on pdfs...

I know.  I was using A4 as an illustration.  But... I reckon 1500cm x 20cm at 1000 dpi (really?) at 8 bits per channel is just under 3GB uncompressed.  Is that sensible?  And, as @Friede implies, 600 graphics on a single page, regardless of size - I can't imagine what message could be communicated like that.  My brain couldn't take that much information in at one go.

The point was to be able to scroll left-right and not up-down but afaik there is absolutely no way to change the scroll direction in a pdf.

Have you tried increasing definition/resolution?

Also, using 10 columns causes the same error. We thought about using multiple pages with fewer plots in a row but they were still cut.

@YacineHajji yes, no changes.

I would go step by step trying to save fewer plots, with fewer cols and play with resolution and see how the arguments behave ones with each other

@YacineHajji I tried many differend combinations now. Unfortunately, even with 1 row and 1 column at any size and resolution (20:40cm, 300dpi and so on) Plot1 and Plot2 are missing. So as soon as I use marrangeGrob() / arrangeGrob() I don't get 3 plots per list item but 1.

Try converting the output of patchwork to a grob with cowplot::as_grob(). The following works for me:
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(gridExtra)
library(cowplot)

example1 <- function(x)
{
  Plot1 <- ggplot(iris[x,], aes(x= Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
    geom_point()
  
  Plot2 <- ggplot(iris[x,], aes(x= Species, y=Sepal.Width))+
    geom_point()
  
  Plot3 <- ggplot(iris[x,], aes(x= Species, y=Petal.Length))+
    geom_point()
  
  as_grob(Plot1 / Plot2 / Plot3)
}

vec <- c(1:150)

ListP <- lapply(vec, example1)

ggsave("test.pdf", arrangeGrob(grobs = ListP, ncol=150), device = "pdf",
       width = 1500, height = 20,
       units = c("cm"), dpi = 300, limitsize = FALSE)


This solution worked for me, thanks! Just one additional info: I found that 'plot_grid(Plot1, Plot2, Plot3, ncol=1)'  (package cowplot) also works. It seems like the issue appears when combining any patchwork with arrangeGrob().
